# How do I get an array to compare its value to a double?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Help! sorry but my instructor simply won't help me, I've emailed her several times and asked her in person but she won't help me..

The point of this program is to use 3 arrays to store the first name, last name, and a grade average. I've put this in a loop to work with five students. At the end of the program I am supposed to call a function that takes the grade average, and turns it into a letter grade (A, B, C, D, F) however I just don't understand the syntax I guess. You can't compare the value of an array to the value of a double, so how is this possible to do?

Note: I have to use 3 arrays and a function to return a letter grade, it is required or she will fail me. This is also my first post ever on here so I'm sorry if I messed this up in some way. Below is my code.

```
// Zachary Law      Array.cpp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

char function1(double Favg, int i);

int main()
{   

    int x, i;
    string Fname[10];
    string Lname[10];
    double Favg[10];
    i=0;
    x=1;

    cout << "We will be working with five students." << endl << endl;
    while (x<=5)
    {
        cout << "Enter first name of student " << x << ": " << endl;
        cin >> Fname[i];

        cout << "Enter last name of student " << x << ": " << endl;
        cin >> Lname[i];

        cout << "Enter grade average of student " << x << ": " << endl;
        cin >> Favg[i];
        i++;
        x++;
    }

    x=0;
    cout << "Name:" << setw(20) << "Final Grade";
    i=5;

    while (x<=5)
    {
        cout << Lname[i] << ", " << Fname[i] << setw(15) << function1(Favg, i);
        cout << endl;
        i--;
        x++;
    }
    return 0;
}

char function1(double Favg, int i)
{
    if (Favg >= 90.00)
        return 'A';
    else if (Favg >= 80.00)
        return 'B';
    else if (Favg >= 70.00)
        return 'C';
    else if (Favg >= 60.00)
        return 'D';
    else if (Favg < 60.00)
        return 'F';
}​
```

Comment: `function1()` should take `i` and `Favg` as arguments, they shouldn't be defined locally within it, and it should operate on `Favg[i]` rather than `Favg[10]`. If you don't know how to pass arguments to functions you should go back to your instructor and tell her she's a lousy teacher.

Comment: I went and edited the code again, how does that look? still not compliling though, unexpected end of file error.

Answer (score 0):

the array Favg should be assign an initial value， or you can pass as function parameters.